# How to stop execution of an async function when input is recieved in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

As title states i'm testing some stuff with  standard library and i got confused on how to make sure when exactly input was recieved. My code looks like this:

```
static bool s_cinGet = false;

std::string CycleWords(std::vector<std::string> Words)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (!s_cinGet)
    {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << Words[i] << std::endl;
        i++;
        i = i % Words.size();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    if (i != 0) i--;
    else i = Words.size() - 1;
    return Words[i];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> Words = { "Tunti", "Triliteral", "Carl" };

    while (true)
    {
        s_cinGet = false;
        auto future = std::async(CycleWords, Words);
        std::cin.get();
        s_cinGet = true;

        std::string word = future.get();

        //system("cls");
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is really simple. It cycles through some words till user presses any key and prints the last word. I want to make sure that the last word was exactly the same word when the user pressed a key. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Try printing the cycle process to another console \ same console with different text.
And then see if those word are the same.

Comment: The code writes to `s_cinGet` from one thread and reads from it in another. That means that the behavior of the program is undefined. Change the type of `s_cinGet` from `bool` to `std::atomic<bool>` to get rid of that issue. Didn't post this as an answer to the question because there's really no question in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks, i appreciate it. I was aware that the behaviour of the program is undefined and how to change it was my whole question to be honest and your solution makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PeteBecker suggested, changing `s_cinGet` from `bool` to `std::atomic<bool>` gets rid of undefined behaviour. Problem solved.